# Google Game Play Services: Neither onSignInFailed or onSignInSuceeded called after aborted sign in attempt

Tags: android, google-play-games, onactivityresult

OK, so here's the problem:

- User presses button to log into Google Play Game Services
- User presses the 'Home' button.
- They the re-launch the app and it carries on trying to log in
- After the Google Play Games logo/dialog disappears, it just returns to the game's menu and is not signed in.

Behind the scenes in my code, this is what happens

- When user presses the scores button, I trigger **getGameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();** which starts the log-in process
- Home key is pressed and app is resumed.
- **onActivityResult** indicates that the Sign-in activity aborted by returning 0 as it's result code.
- onSignInFailed is triggered as sign-in failed
- It then tries sign-in again.  This time **onActivityResult**, returns -1 (success!)

That's as far as it gets. We're left not signed in and neither success or failure callback is triggered.

Why does it not attempt to sign in again?

**Edit**

Interestingly, if I put the following:

```
 gameHelper().reconnectClient();
```

Into my **onActivityResult** method, it seems to trigger an automatic additional attempt to connect and therefore the calls one of the **onSignIn**callbacks:  I don't really understand why this seems to fix it?  What I mean is why doesn't starting the sign-on process (the activity that I get a result from) actually trigger an attempt to connect?  Am I getting myself confused here? :-/

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int request, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(request, resultCode, data);      

    //Game Services sign-in action
    if (request == 9001){

        //Failure
        if resultCode != -1{
            getGameHelper().reconnectClient();
        }


    }

}
```

**Edit**

The above doesn't work for instances where the app is paused and then returned too after the device has been left for some time (presumably the system has freed up some resources) In this case again **onActivityResult** is successful but again, it doesn't sign in and onSignInFailed (or onSignInSucceeded) are **not** called.

Comment: Are you using `GameHelper`? Are you also using `BaseGameActivity`?

Comment: Yeah, my mainActivity class is extending BaseGameActivity and I'm using GameHelper for things like setMaxAutoSignInAttempts(0) and beginUserInitiatedSignIn(); - Please see my edit.  It seems to work now but I could do with an explanation of some kind as to why because I'm not sure that really get how this works - why do I need to explicitly have a reconnect here? Shouldn't starting the Sign-On activity automatically trigger an actual attempt to sign on?

Comment: When did you last update your `BaseGameUtils`? It was last updated just 4 days ago (July 2, 2014).

Comment: Interesting - It was longer than that - I integrated it into my project about 2 months ago.  Haven't touched it since........ I'll have a look at that.... cheers!